# Meta Off-Topic close reason makes no sense

Tags: support, status-completed, closing, meta

We got new close reasons! Yay!

It looks like we can have a different set of custom closures for Off-Topic on Meta. I don't think we need anything fancy here, but what we have now is just nonsense.

> This question does not appear to be about on-topic, within the scope defined in the help center.

I too would like to see more questions about on-topic.

Comment: Haha!  Take that, gravity!

Comment: Why, obviously we're [supposed to replace our mod-only tags by close reasons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sH07x.png).

Comment: [tag:allowed-questions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the default close reason to

> This question does not appear to be about [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), within the scope defined in the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).